# Secure a specific path with just username password and others with jwt token in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, configuration

I have configured Swagger in my Spring Boot application, all the controllers are secured with OAuth2 protocol but I want my `/swagger-ui/**` path to be secured by simple username password which can be hardcoded here. I can't find a way to implement two different authentication for different endpoints.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("in configure HttpSecurity");
    http
        .mvcMatcher("/v1/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/webhook/stripe/**").anonymous()
            .mvcMatchers("/forgotPassword/**").anonymous()
            .mvcMatchers("/public/**").anonymous()
            // Any request simply requires authentication, regardless of permissions.
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                .decoder(jwtDecoder())
                    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
            )
        );

    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    return http.build();
}
```

I tried creating another filter chain with `Order(1)`-

```java
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password("12345")
            .build();
    http
        .mvcMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
        .userDetailsService(new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin));
    return http.build();
}
```

I expected it to work like a filter chain and try to authenticate it first, but it didn't work that way.

Comment: Your second configuration missed `@Bean` annotation and `formLogin()` for username and password authentication. Also change `mvcMatcher` with `securityMatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http.securityMatcher(...)` in the first `SecurityFilterChain` in `@Order` for it to apply just to a few routes and have the second in order act as default (I would set an explicit order to the two and a security matcher only to the first).

P.S.
If you setup this username / password for a programmatic client, have you considered using client-credentials flow to get an access token and have your API secured with just the resource server filter chain?